# Don't use android's built in org.json

Tags: java, android, json, android-gradle-plugin, org.json

I've written a library that uses [`org.json`](http://json.org/) (A) from json.org, under the assumption that Android used the same (in android it's also called `org.json` (B), just that it misses some relatively critical features). Now what I'd like to do is set up my gradle, so that my project uses [`org.json`](http://json.org/) (A) instead of `org.json` (B). I've tried adding the following to my app.gradle:

```
android {
    blabla
    defaultConfig {
        blabla
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets{
        main{
            java{
                exclude 'org/json/**'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, this does not seem to work. I still have Android's `org.json` (B) available to me, and when typing `new JSONObject()` it still uses Android's implementation. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could I fix this?

Change yours from `org.json` to `org.something.else`. You cannot replace system-supplied packages with ones from an app, even for your own process. You do not control the runtime classpath, and the firmware always wins.

Or, switch from `org.json` to something that performs better, such as Gson or Jackson.

Answer (score 3):

You can relocate your `org.json` dependency to another package name.
This can be done with the gradle shadow plugin.

Plugin project: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow
Plugin documentation: https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/

My working example:
Hint: I'm using a java library project "lib" within my Android project which has a dependency to `org.json`.

**lib/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:4.0.3'
    }
}

shadowJar {
    relocate 'org.json', 'shadow.org.json'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('org.json:json:20180813')
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    [..]
}

dependencies {
    [..]
    implementation project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'shadow')
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed!