# org.json.JSONTokener : no constructor from Reader

Tags: java, android, org.json

In an Android (API 30 but also API 26), Java project I have this dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20210307'
```

but the following fails because it can not find the requested constructor (`org.json.JSONTokener(Reader ...)`) and it insists that the only constructor is with a `String`:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(responseBody.byteStream());
org.json.JSONTokener jst = new org.json.JSONTokener(reader);
```

```
error: incompatible types: Reader cannot be converted to String
```

Am I using a specific org.json implementation which lacks this feature or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you are missing the fact that google made org.json part of android framework ... so without repackaging you cannot use different version than it's on android itself

Comment: Indeed, even without adding that dependency, org.json was found. That's fine, so the android version has only the String constructor? What would be the best way then to make my own JSON tokener from a ```responseBody.byteStream()``` (to be used with Retrofit's response body).

Comment: thanks for the hint, perhaps this can be of help to others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803776/dont-use-androids-built-in-org-json

Comment: What I finally did was to get https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java  , modify its namespace to ```org.json.XYZ``` and added the compiled JAR as a dependency to my project. There is also the possibility of a gradle plugin to shadow the namespace which I have not tried but is mentioned in the link in my other comment. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.